# Glide won't Load images from a URL and crashes the app

Tags: android, android-glide

So I am having an issue where even the most barebones implementation of `Glide` to load an image won't work and results in a AppX has stopped. I even created a side app with just the necessary code required to load from a URL and it doesn't work. I have tried several URLs that I know work and get the same issue. I have added the permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

the gradle instructions:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
```

and my activity XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.benhouse.basicglidetest.MainActivity">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Hello World!"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="138dp"
android:layout_height="495dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="192dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="155dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my .java for that activity:

```
package com.example.benhouse.basicglidetest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://i.imgur.com/AxETlhd.jpg");
    }
}
```

What is going wrong? I am not getting any stack traces in the logcat or anything and I have isolated the problem as much as possible. Also is there a way to display on the app that the image didn't load?

Comment: you need to set target to your loadinging: `Glide.with(context).load(url).into(YourView)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this .

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load("https://i.imgur.com/AxETlhd.jpg").into(imageView);
```

Add `into(imageView);` to the code .

**Note**

Adding error image and placehoder image will be well .

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).placeholder(R.mipmap.placeholder).error(R.mipmap.error).into(iv);
```

Comment: I'm an idiot... I forgot to add back the findViewById() method... thanks for the tips on the error and place holder.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this code:

*I had changed some of the lines from your snippet:*

```
    package com.example.benhouse.basicglidetest;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ImageView imageView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourImageView); // get your image view


       Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
        .load("https://i.imgur.com/AxETlhd.jpg")
        .into(imageView); // put image loaded via glide into ImageView
                }
            }
```

Comment: well there's your problem... forgot :imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourImageView); // get your image view

Answer (score 0):

> Add loaded image into imageview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

           Glide.with(EnterPinActivity.this).load("https://i.imgur.com/AxETlhd.jpg").placeholder(R.drawable.plcae_holder).error(R.drawable.plcae_holder).into(imageView);

   }
}
```